# Anyone who knows how to configure the Amazon AWS platform to program skills?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working with Amazon's AWS platform and I need to program Lambda functions that I will need use as Skills for Alexa. But when I have to connect my Lambda function with the Alexa Developer platform I am experiencing problems especially when it asks me to enter the data relating to the linking account.

[image]

The data I entered are these, however, once I turn on my app and go to the skill that I have programmed to activate it on my alexa, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Images of text are not accessible nor are they searchable. They should be augmented with the text that they contain, or replaced with the text that they contain. Right now if someone searches for that error message this question won't come up.

Comment: I think your biggest issue is that you think you need Account Linking. You don't need this (for now). It's needed if you want to connect your skill users with already existing accounts in an other system.  Just see the answer - you only need to configure your lambda endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get your question right- you want to link Alexa Dev Console to the lambda function. First you need to **go to Alexa developer console**. On the **"Build" category** there is a topic called **"Endpoint"**. Click on that. **Copy your skill id and head over to Lambda**. In there you need to **enter the skill id, while creating a function**. After the function is set up, **head to the editor. On the upper right corner of the page you see your "ARN"**. Click on the copy button at the end of the line. **Get back to Alexa developer console**. At **"Endpoint"** you enter the **ARN value in the "default region"**. After saving (at lambda **and** developer console), your link should be established.